# How to implement NSTextFinderClient protocol in NSTextView in Swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextview

I have a NSTextView in which the text is being changed programatically. I have the exact problem mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839265/nstextfinder-set-search-string-and-clear-visual-feedback-programatically) question. But since I am using swift I am getting Compiler error saying "Type of 'string' has different optionality than required by protocol 'NSTextFinderClient'" when I try to implement NSTextFinderClient protocol in NSTextView. I need help in figuring out how to do it correctly.

Comment: Can you provide the code for your conformation to the protocol in your `NSTextView` subclass? Especially the line that triggers the compiling error. I'm guessing you just need to unwrap an optional here.

Comment: The error is shown when I try to build the project, its not shown on a line of code. 
Currently I am implementing the protocol using these two methods `func stringLength() -> Int` and `func stringAtIndex(characterIndex: Int, effectiveRange outRange: NSRangePointer, endsWithSearchBoundary outFlag: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> String`. You can reproduce the error by just conforming an NSTextView subclass to the NSTextFinderClient protocol.

Comment: I think the issue stems from the fact that `NSText` which is a superclass of `NSTextView` already has a `string` property of type `String?` whereas the `string` property defined by `NSTextFinderClient` is a `String` (not optional). I can't think of any solution at the moment, except having another object (which doesn't by default have a `string` property) being the client and having reference to your `NSTextView`, almost like a delegate (never done that)

Comment: I tried that by making the viewcontroller that controls the NSTextView as the NSTextFinder's client, but then none of the methods in the NSTextFinderClient protocol are being invoked.

Comment: You don't actually need the two methods if you provide the `string` property. From the doc: "If the client cannot logically or efficiently flatten itself into a single string, then the stringAtIndex:effectiveRange:endsWithSearchBoundary: and stringLength methods should be implemented instead." Just provide a getter for `string` and you should be good.. I think?

Comment: Something in the likes of `var string: String { get { return self.textView.textStorage!.string } }` with appropriate checking before unwrapping of course.

Comment: Yeah I tried that too, still no luck. The string value declared in the viewController is never fetched while performing findText action.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101673/discussion-between-beeb-and-chintan-ghate).

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem.
Replace this

```
class TextView: NSTextView, NSTextFinderClient {
    var textFinder: NSTextFinder!
}
```

By

```
class TextView: NSTextView {
    @IBOutlet weak var textFinder: NSTextFinder!
}
```

drag and drop a TexTFinder Object into the scene that contains the TextView outlet. Link the TextView's textFinder to the TextFinderObject, and make the TextView the Outlet's client. After this you'll be able to send notifications to the FindBar like `textFinder.noteClientStringWillChange()`
or `textFinder.performAction(.HideFindInterface)`. In doing this we do not need to make TextView object confirm to the NSTextFinderClient protocol programatically.