# Customizing NSTextFinder with case-sensitivity checkbox

Tags: swift, macos, appkit, nstextview

I'm looking to add a checkbox for case-sensitive searches in my `NSTextView`. I've read through the Apple documentation, but the relationship between `NSTextView`, `NSScrollView` and `NSTextFinder` is best described as obfuscated. I am using `performTextFinderAction:` to pass the find actions.

Is there a way to add additional buttons or views to the find bar, or do I have to replace the whole thing? Seems a bit overkill for just adding a single option.

Case-sensitivity is also passed through a pasteboard attribute, although after reading through the documentation, I'm still confused where and when the text view actually checks for the attributes. `NSTextFinderClient` only provides ranges and rects for the matched substrings.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextfindercaseinsensitivekey

I've followed creating my own text finder method using this example:
[NSTextFinder + programmatically changing the text in NSTextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35274070/nstextfinder-programmatically-changing-the-text-in-nstextview)

However, any `NSTextFinder` documentation only covers using the basic find bar it provides, and never touches the subject of customizing it or replacing it altogether.

Any help or pointing to better documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you call `performTextFinderAction:` or is it implemented and in which class? Do you want to customize text finding or only the find bar? What do you mean by "Case-sensitivity is also passed through a pasteboard attribute"?

Comment: I don't think you can add a button to the find bar, you have to use the drop-down menu. The find panel has a checkbox.

Comment: I'd like to add case-sensitivity, but in the future, would like to customize the whole text finding, if I get there. I am calling `performTextFinderAction:`, now implemented in my `NSTextView` subclass to provide the custom `NSTextFinder`. `super.performTextFinderAction` seems to exist in every view in the enclosing scroll view.

Comment: Text finder options are passed through pasteboard attributes: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextfindercaseinsensitivekey
— this is why I was wondering where and when exactly should I pass it, but it's clear that I'd have to create my own find panel anyway to implement this.